# How come hash code of key depends up on the capacity of the Hash map

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

When the Hash map is filled in the proportion of load factor (.75) and if it exceeds it, capacity will get doubled and rehashing occurs which results in rearrangement of entries.

In this context, how come the hash code of any key depends up on the capacity of Hash map such that rearrangement will happen? If any key's hash code is 10 (say), how come it gets affected when the capacity of the hash map changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `hashCode` doesn't change when the `HashMap`'s capacity grows. However, when you have to map a `hashCode` whose value is (for example) 503 into a `HashMap` of (for example) 64 buckets, you use the modulus operator (i.e. `hashCode() % 64`), which will map you to bucket #55.

When the capacity of the `HashMap` is doubled to 128 buckets, applying the modulus operator on the same `hashCode` (this time `hashCode() % 128`) will map that same `hashCode` to a different bucket (bucket #119).

I simplified the answer a bit. The modulus is not applied directly on the `hashCode`. It is applied on the result of applying another internal hashing function on the `hashCode`. This doesn't change the explanation though.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your bucket index is based on size of your hash map capacity. As per java doc method indexFor return the bucket index I.e.

static into indexFor(int h, int length){
 return h & (length-1)
}